# Reducing terms in the series expansion of a function of two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I have a function $f(x, y)$.

This function is such that

\begin{align}
f(0, y)=a\\
f(x, 0)=a,
\end{align}

where $a$ is a constant.

From this, a particular mathematician concludes:

> Thus if we expand $f$ about $a$ as a series in $(x, y)$, then the lowest order terms will have the form
>
> \begin{align}
> f=a+Axy,
> \end{align}
>
> where $A=\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x \partial y}$.

***How did the mathematician get to this conclusion?***

When I write out the Taylor series expansion of $f$ at $(0, 0)$, I get a very different result.  (But maybe this isn't what the mathematician is saying he did.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the condition is that $f(x,0)=a$ **for all $x$**, and similarly for $f(0,y)=a$.  Then by definition
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h, 0)-f(0, 0)}h
  =\lim_{h\to0}\frac{a-a}h=0\ .$$
In fact, a very similar calculation gives
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,0)=0$$
for all $x$, and hence
$$\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(0,0)=0\ .$$
This (with similar calculations for $\frac\partial{\partial y}$) accounts for the "missing" terms in the series.